# ASP.NET login form authentication without login control

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, form-authentication

I am using ASP.NET membership and on registration page trying to login without a login control.

When user clicks on the register button, the control goes to redirect.aspx page.
But in that page, while I am trying to redirect to the members homepage its throwing the following error.

ERROR -

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame
is on top of the call stack.
```

Web.config -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".SSOAuth" loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Redirect.aspx"
           protection="Validation" timeout="30000"/>
</authentication>
```

RegistrationPage code -

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser userMemb = Membership.CreateUser(
                           txtemail.Text.Replace("'", "''").ToString(),
                           txtPassword.Text.Replace("'", "''").ToString(),
                           txtemail.Text.ToString());

    Roles.AddUserToRole(txtemail.Text.ToString(), "Member");
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtemail.Text.Trim(), false);
}
```

Redirect.aspx.cs code -

```
try
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Member"))
    {
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name;                        
        Response.Redirect("~/Member/MembeHome.aspx");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this document (issue and solution) [ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us)

Use [Response.Redirect(url,false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
Response.Redirect("~/Member/MembeHome.aspx",false);
```